# Checkpoints implementation in huggingface

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, large-language-model

I have a dataset that is 22 million rows that I would like to grab the embeddings for from a huggingface transformer model. I want to embed the input_ids I got from the tokenization process. The code below takes 5 hours to embed 20% of the dataset and then it crashes.
I'm looking for:

1. How to implement checkpoints with this code so that I don't have to be worried if it crashes
2. How to make it run faster (I am using 2 NVIDIAA100_SXM4_80GB GPUs). I've already tried increasing the batch size-- whenever I increase the batch size above 2000, it says the GPU has run out of memory.

```
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("InstaDeepAI/nucleotide-transformer-500m-human-ref", num_labels=2)
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model)
model = model.to(device)

ds1 = Dataset.from_file('data_train') # already tokenized

def embed_function(examples):
    inputs = torch.tensor(examples['input_ids'])  # Convert to tensor
    inputs = inputs.to(device)

    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(input_ids=inputs, output_hidden_states=True)
    
    # Step 3: Extract the embeddings
    hidden_states = outputs.hidden_states  # List of hidden states from all layers
    embeddings = hidden_states[-1]  # Assuming you want embeddings from the last layer

    return {'embeddings': embeddings}

embedding1 = ds1.map(
    embed_function,
    batched=True, batch_size=2000)

embedding1
embedding1.save_to_disk("embeddings/train", num_shards=1)
```